# Firebase storage returning strange results for snapshot.bytesTransferred

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to calculate the percentage of progress of an image upload to Firebase storage in React Native, however `snapshot.bytesTransferred` sent by Firebase server is showing erratic values.

```
firebase.storage().
    ref().
    child('images').
    child('randomFileName').
    put(blob, {contentType: 'image/png'}).
    on('state_changed',
        progressCallback, // This is the upload progress callback
        (error) => {
          alert(error.message);
        },
        () => {
          successCallback(randomKey);
        });
```

This is `progressCallback` function, it basically set a state calculating the percentage of bytes already transferred compared to the total number of bytes of the file.

The [percentage formula](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files?hl=en#monitor_upload_progress) was taken from official React documentation:

```
(snapshot) => {
  let pct = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

  console.debug('snapshot.totalBytes: ' + snapshot.totalBytes);
  console.debug('snapshot.bytesTransferred: ' + snapshot.bytesTransferred);
  console.debug('percentage: ' + pct);

  let state = this.state;
  state.pct = pct;
  this.setState(state);
}
```

However, snapshot.bytesTransferred returns erratic results:

```
snapshot.totalBytes: 882722
snapshot.bytesTransferred: 0
percentage: 0

snapshot.totalBytes: 882722
snapshot.bytesTransferred: 010240
percentage: 1.1600481238713887

snapshot.totalBytes: 882722
snapshot.bytesTransferred: 0262144
percentage: 29.697231971107552

snapshot.totalBytes: 882722
snapshot.bytesTransferred: 262144
percentage: 29.697231971107552

snapshot.totalBytes: 882722
snapshot.bytesTransferred: 26214410240
percentage: 2969724.3571588793

snapshot.totalBytes: 882722
snapshot.bytesTransferred: 262144450560
percentage: 29697283.013225004

snapshot.totalBytes: 882722
snapshot.bytesTransferred: 786432
percentage: 89.09169591332265

snapshot.totalBytes: 882722
snapshot.bytesTransferred: 78643240960
percentage: 8909174.231524762

snapshot.totalBytes: 882722
snapshot.bytesTransferred: 882722
percentage: 100
```

As you can see in the example code, I'm not casting the returned values to Int or anything that changes the results Firebase sent me. Should I be doing something else?

Details:

- [firebase@5.8.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) (also tried 4.9.1, same results).
- image.png, which is being uploaded, has 882722 bytes (863kb).
- Value returned from snapshot.totalBytes is 882722, which is correct.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue...

Comment: @hugger No, sorry. I haven't worked with Firebase in a while